# Items doesn't display in combobox wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Name="cmbPlayer1" IsEditable="true"></ComboBox>
```

and I initialize my Combobox with data from database. I have procedure which initialize  this and then I call this procedure.

```
Public Sub InitComboxesPlayers(cmbPlayer As ComboBox)
    Using myDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetSqlFunctions.GetExecutedDataReaderFromSql(
         "SELECT PLAYER_ID,        " &
         "       PLAYER_NICKNAME,  " &
         "       PLAYER_FIRSTNAME, " &
         "       PLAYER_LASTNAME   " &
         "  FROM PLAYERS ", myConnection)

        While myDataReader.Read
            Dim myNewPlayer As New Players
            With myNewPlayer
                .Player_ID = CInt(myDataReader("PLAYER_ID"))
                .Nickname = myDataReader("PLAYER_NICKNAME").ToString.Trim
                .Firstname = myDataReader("PLAYER_FIRSTNAME").ToString.Trim
                .Lastname = myDataReader("PLAYER_LASTNAME").ToString.Trim
            End With
            lstOfPlayers.Add(myNewPlayer)
        End While
    End Using

    cmbPlayer.ItemsSource = lstOfPlayers
    cmbPlayer.DataContext = lstOfPlayers
    cmbPlayer.DisplayMemberPath = "PLAYER_NICKNAME"
    cmbPlayer.SelectedValuePath = "PLAYER_ID"

End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitComboxesPlayers(cmbPlayer1)

End Sub
```

So, my values does not display in combobox. But you can see on the picture that values are in Combobox, because it's not empty. What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: DisplayMember should be `Nickname` not `PLAYER_NICKNAME`

Comment: Ok, I have it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... you need to ***assign the property names from your class***, not the column names from your sql...

```
 cmbPlayer.DisplayMemberPath = "Nickname"
 cmbPlayer.SelectedValuePath = "Player_ID"
```

Answer (score -1):

Two Approaches :-

1) Update your code to use the property instead of DataBase Column names :-

```
cmbPlayer.DisplayMemberPath = "Nickname "
```

2) You can create an Item template for your combo box, so you don't need to set the DisplayMemberPath in your Code.

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Name="cmbPlayer1" IsEditable="true">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Nickname}
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```